# getting "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" while trying to convert the entire dataset to english using google translate

Tags: python, google-translation-api

I saw similar questions in stack overflow but I wanted to get more specific with this : entire dataset using google translate

```
translator = Translator()
df_en = df.copy()

translations = {}
for column in df.columns:
     #translator = Translator()
     unique_elements = df[column].unique() # Getting unique elements of the column
     for element in unique_elements:
         translator = Translator()
         translations[element] = translator.translate(element).text

print(translations)
```

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      8     for element in unique_elements:
      9         translator = Translator()
---> 10         translations[element] = translator.translate(element).text
     11 
     12 print(translations)

6 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Answer (score 0):

I was working XML file for translate and I was getting this error "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)". When I searched this error, I encountered that some special characters fails translation. In this case `&nbsp; &amp; etc.` were problem for me. If there are special characters in your text, copy-paste to google translate web-site and see is there a error.

Another reason for this errors can be about too much request or character limit. If you are using list instead of string, Each index in your list means a new request for translation. If there are too much request, google bans your IP for a time.

I collect my texts in a string variable. I add [text number] to begining of each text and seperates them with /n then sending to tranlation. Like;

`[1]First Text\n
[2]SecondText\n
[3]Third Text\n`

Google Translate can translate 10000 characters in single request so character limit is 10000 for a string variable. Also I add a timer for 100 seconds between each requests to escape from ban. Its working for me.

PS: You can use list instead of string. You just need a loop like this;

`list[0] = max 10K characters
Send to Translate
timer for 100 seconds
list[1] = max 10K characters
Send to Translate
timer for 100 seconds
.
.`